# Package acro, word gender feminine and masculine in French

Tags: acro

I'm writing a document in French and I have to deal with gender forms of words with the `acro` package.
I would like to produce something like

> tridimensionnelles (3D) (a feminine form) or bidimensionnel (2D) (for a masculine form)

With the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[version=3]{acro} %list of abbreviations

\acsetup{
    list/template = longtable,
    list/display = used,
    uppercase/list,
    format/alt
}
\DeclareAcronym{2d}{
    short   = 2D,
    long    = bidimensionnel,
    alt-format = tridimensionnelles}
\DeclareAcronym{3d}{
    short   = 3D,
    long    = tridimensionnel,
    alt = tridimensionnelles}

\begin{document}
\ac{2d} is masculine gender form.
\newline
\aca{3d} is the feminine gender form, but there is not the short form (3D).
\end{document}
```

I can produce text like

[image]

But the 3D in parenthesis not appear.

Do you have any idea to deal with gender forms with the `acro` package?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Instead of posting a code fragment, it's more helpful to put the fragment into a compilable document that people can play with.

Comment: Hello @AlanMunn and thank you for your corrections. I've added a compilable document.

Comment: `\aca` is just printing the `alt` form it's working as intended,  `alt` is meant as an alternative short form, so `\aca` is more of a stand-in for `\acs` than `\ac` or `\acf`.  You might be trying to set plural forms and so want to set `long-plural-form=les` when declaring, but I'm not quite clear, could you give a couple more usages of the acro commands and what you want them to expand to?

Comment: As an example with "2D", I would like to define the plural form "bidimensionnels" and the feminine form "bidimensionnelle" and to be able to use "bidimensionnelles" form, i.e feminine plural.
I will check ```long-plural-form=les```

Comment: @nicolasEmoptisie I think I see, `long-plural-form` probably isn't enough. So essentially you want a masculine and feminine version of each acro command (e.g. `\ac` can be called with `\acmasc` or `\acfem`, `\acs` having `\acsmasc` and `\acsfem`) or does the gender only come up in specific cases/forms?

Comment: Yes, exactly @DaiBowen.

Answer (score 1):

[`acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro) has interfaces for defining arbitrary new properties with `\DeclareAcroProperty`, and new commands with `\NewAcroCommand` detailed in the documentation in sections *29. Properties* and *30. Own acronym commands*.

However, for defining multiple properties and an internal interface, I think `\DeclareAcroEnding` can be slightly misused to good effect.
`\DeclareAcroEnding{feminine}{}{}` defines `*-feminine` and `*-feminine-form` equivalents to the `*-plural` and `*-plural-form` that are all initially empty.
Where the feminine form differs by letters appended to the masculine form `long-feminine=les` can be set, or where it differs more substantially `long-feminine-form=tridimensionelles` can be used to state it in its entirety.

Then we need to add new `\ac`-variants to apply these properties, e.g.

```
\NewAcroCommand \acF {m}
  { \acrofeminine \UseAcroTemplate {first} {#1} }
\NewAcroCommand \AcF {m}
  { \acrofeminine \acroupper \UseAcroTemplate {first} {#1} }
```

(note I'm using `F` to avoid clashing with the already existing `\acf`-type commands that force the full appearance).
Other variants need to be explicitly defined individually but can be based on the definitions found [in the source](https://github.com/cgnieder/acro/blob/master/code/acro.definitions.code.tex).

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{acro}[=v3]

\DeclareAcroEnding{feminine}{}{}

\DeclareAcronym{2d}{
    short   = 2D,
    long    = bidimensionnel,
    long-feminine=les,
}
\DeclareAcronym{3d}{
    short   = 3D,
    long    = tridimensionnel,
    long-feminine-form=tridimensionnelles,
}

\NewAcroCommand \acF {m}
  { \acrofeminine \UseAcroTemplate {first} {#1} }
\NewAcroCommand \AcF {m}
  { \acrofeminine \acroupper \UseAcroTemplate {first} {#1} }

\begin{document}
\ac{2d} \acreset{2d} \acF{2d}

\acF{3d} \acreset{3d} \ac{3d}

\printacronyms[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

[image: Code output]

For the feminine plural, I think we have to declare a separate ending `\DeclareAcroEnding{feminineplural}{s}{s}` using the same default as for the `plural` ending.
Unfortunately I don't see how we can inherit the `feminine` endings, so this will require some duplication, even if the plural just appends an s.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{acro}[=v3]

\DeclareAcroEnding{feminine}{}{}
\DeclareAcroEnding{feminineplural}{s}{s}

\DeclareAcronym{2d}{
    short   = 2D,
    long    = bidimensionnel,
    long-feminine=les,
    long-feminineplural=less
}

\NewAcroCommand \acpF {m}
  { \acrofeminineplural \UseAcroTemplate {first} {#1} }

\begin{document}
\acp{2d} \acreset{2d} \acpF{2d}

\printacronyms[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

[image: Code output]

---

A slightly nicer interface than exploiting `\DeclareAcroEnding` probably could be built, but not without either a lot of boiler plate code or relying on the `expl3` interface.

Answer (score 0):

The lazy solution, when you have one acronym that may take two forms which differ arbitrarily (whether in one or all of the short/long/first/plural/etc), is to define two tightly connected acronyms.

The `uselist` property of an acronym allows the acronyms `2d` and `2dB` allows `2d` to consider itself used if `2dB` has been used, even if it has not itself, and vice versa.

```
\DeclareAcronym{2d}{
    short   = 2D,
    long    = bidimensionnel,
    uselist = {2dB},
}
\DeclareAcronym{2dB}{
    short   = 2D,
    long    = bidimensionnelB,
    uselist = {2d},
}
```

The two acronyms can differ as much or as little (even not at all if necessary) and within the text will not share a common first usage.  This can be extended to an arbitrary number of acronyms if necessary.

There are a few caveats coming from pairing up acronyms like this though:

- Resetting usage remains local to the acronym, `\acreset{2d}` will only reset `2d` while, if it has been used, `2dB` will still remember it was used.
- `\acsetup{single=true}` will give unexpected behaviour if both are used but one of them is only used once.
- As we have two acronyms the `\printacronyms` will list both unless their list form is identical (e.g. if they share a short/long form but differ on plural properties).  This can be resolved by tagging one of the acronyms and using `exclude` in `\printacronyms`

  ```
  \DeclareAcronym{2d}{
      short   = 2D,
      long    = bidimensionnel,
      uselist = {2dB},
  }
  \DeclareAcronym{2dB}{
      short   = 2D,
      long    = bidimensionnelB,
      uselist = {2d},
      tag = {B-form},
  }

  \begin{document}
  \ac{2d}    
  \ac{2dB}

  \printacronyms[heading=none,exclude={B-form}]
  \end{document}
  ```

  however this too can have unexpected consequences if only `2dB` ends up being used in the document and `\acsetup{list/display=used}` is set.